# How can php-files find namespaces in other php-files?

Tags: php, python, import, namespaces

Coming from Python I'm trying to make sense of the way php uses namespaces. In Python I simply import as follows:

```
import someModule
from anotherModule import someClass
```

This works like a charm and exactly like anyone would expect.

In php on the other hand, we've got something like namespaces. As far as I understand I can define a namespace on the top of a myModule.php like this:

```
namespace myNamespace;
```

If I'm correct this means that the code in this file can be referred to as (or imported by) the name "myNamespace" in another myWorkingCode.php by doing this:

```
use myNamespace;
```

So my question; How does myWorkingCode.php find the myModule.php? Does it need to be in the same folder for this to work or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Check [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#113069) and [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#105394)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use function in php is completly different then the import in python.

Use is there for creating aliases for very long namespaces. example:

```
use \My\Very\Long\Omg\Its\Sooooo\Long\How\Stupid as veryshort;
```

Now every class inside that long namespace is available under the namespace veryshort. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Then, how does php find the correct file? It doesn't. You will have to include it yourself, however if you use a strong naming convention for your files you can use autoloaders with the [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function. A good standard can be found here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/0/

Comment: Ah alright. I am slowly making sense out of it. So if I want to import classes from a php-file I always have to manually include() the file right? And the addition of the namespace is just so that no namespace colisions occur with other included files which might have classes named the same. Am I correct?